# Jsp doesn't see included taglibs. Seems to be a local webshpere 6 configuration issue?

Tags: jsp, websphere, compilation, taglib

Ill try to be as descriptive as possible.

situation:
struts tag's not being resolved on a jsp.  When you look at what should resolve as links you see:

```
<html:link page="/dto/initDTO.do"><b><i>Design To Order Control System ( DTOCS )</i></b></html:link>
```

Which leads me to believe that the struts tag is not being resolved.

The source of this page includes:

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp" %>
```

And if you look at that jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri='/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-template.tld' prefix='template' %>
<%@ taglib uri='/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-html.tld' prefix='html' %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/cat-input.tld" prefix="input" %>
<% String URLRoot = request.getContextPath(); %>
```

If you look at the web.xml:

```
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-template.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-template.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/webTrends.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/webTrends.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Without re-pasting the folder structure.. the pathing for the tlds is correct.  I can also tell you that I've checked the classloader, and the struts jar is loaded.

Now, This is running on my local websphere 6 server, which is spun up by IBM RAD.  When I check  this project out, the links do not resolve on my local.  BUT, when my teammate checks it out, it runs on his local.  I have obviously made sure that I have followed the same steps for running this app locally as my teammate has.  This app also runs on our websphere TEST, QA, and PROD environments.  So, this situation is only specific to my box.

Answer (score 0):

(What error do you see? 404 or something else?)

Some ideas:

Are both you and your colleague using the same setting for resources on server or in workspace?

Have you tried taking a copy of their workspace?

Are you running *exactly* the same version of WAS? Did your colleague apply any fixes to their test environment or RAD.

Answer (score 0):

Finally...

Upgraded WTE to 6.0.2.3 from 6.0.0.0, and taglibs are now resolved.

Not sure exactly what the prob was there, just that the older WTE couldn't do it.

-Tim